# How to define prefixes in XML and use them in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having trouble with prefixes. The XML shows the headline and th but the rest is blank.

I've tried defining the prefixes both in the XSL and xml different places as well as using different URI. Tbh I don't really understand the use of URI. Where do I find the good ones? And/or is there other mistakes in my code? I've tried to search around for similar questions, but didn't understand :/

Here's the code of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="testsortalpha.xsl"?>

<catalog xmlns:ccc="http://www.w3.org" xmlns:aaa="http://www.w3.org">

<ccc:bbb>

<aaa:entry><b>def</b></aaa:entry>

<aaa:entry><b>abc</b></aaa:entry>

<aaa:entry><b>cde</b></aaa:entry>

<aaa:entry><b>bcd</b></aaa:entry>

</ccc:bbb>
</catalog>
```

Here's the code of the XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">Test</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/ccc/aaa">
      <xsl:sort select="b"/>
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="b"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the namespaces in the stylesheet and use them as namespace prefixes in the XPath expressions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ccc="http://www.w3.org"
                xmlns:aaa="http://www.w3.org">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">Test</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/ccc:bbb/aaa:entry">
      <!--                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
      <xsl:sort select="b"/>
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="b"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```